# Starting with Java, syntax error on tokens

Tags: java, syntax, token

For some reason its highlighting boolean and string as errors, I copied this code straight out of the textbook why wont it work? 
package practice;

```
public class practice{

public boolean isUniqueChars(string str){
if (str.length() > 256)
            return false;

        boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
        for (int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++){
            int val = str.charAt(i);
            if (char_set[val]) {
                return false;

            char_set[val] = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
Errors: Multiple markers at this line
- string cannot be resolved to a type
- Syntax error on token "boolean", @ 
 expected
- Syntax error on token ")", -> expected
- Syntax error on token(s), misplaced 
 construct(s)
```

Comment: Where is your class definition, from git link it has only method body, do you mean you copied the method to your class body? please post your complete code.

Comment: you are trying to store your value on char index and array index can be int only. replace char_set[val] to char_set[i].

Comment: public boolean isUniqueChars(string str) - string should begin with caps "String"

Comment: @ManojSharma Any type that can be promoted to an `int` is allowed.

Comment: It's `String` with a capital S, not `string` with a lower-case s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Try this:

```
package practice;

/**
 *
 * @author manoj.sharma
 */

public class Test{
public static void main(String [] a){
System.out.println(new Test().isUniqueChars("Hello world"));
}
public boolean isUniqueChars(String str){
    if (str.length() > 256)
        return false;

    boolean[] char_set = new boolean[256];
    for (int i = 0; i< str.length(); i++){
        int val = str.charAt(i);
        if (char_set[val]) {
            return false;
        }
        char_set[val] = true;
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Well now theres no errors but running it says theres no previous launch, why won't my code execute?

Comment: Problem which i have identified is typo error. you have written String as string, String first letter must be capital as String is a class not primitive.

Comment: When I click the green run error, it says:
Unable to Launch: The selection cannot be launched, and there are no recent launches

Comment: what tool you are using.

Comment: do you have main method in your code. actually i am using netbeans and i my tool program executing without error.

Comment: go to oracle site to learn in depth. or you can try these site to learn more about java and netbeans. http://www.learnjavaonline.org/, https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/learn-java.html, http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/basicjava1-135508.html.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean isUniqueChars(string str){
```

seems a typo, **string** should be `String`

Answer (score 0):

Use "S" for String declaration in Java.

```
isUniqueChars(String str)
```